# Showing data from multiple elements using $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a script that echoes out the last dropped droppable element, I want to make it so when the last element is dropped all the elements dropped previous to the last one being dropped is echoed out. [This here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/248/) is a visual of the script minus the echoing out. Below is the javscript containing the issue.

```
$('#dropbox, #dropbox1').droppable({
        accept: '.sort',
        hoverClass: 'border',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drop: function(e, ui) {
    $(this).append(ui.draggable.html() + '<br/>');
            $("#add_friend").show().fadeOut(12000);
            $(e.target).droppable("disable");
            $(e.target).append("<input type='button' name='Sub' value='clear'/>").click(function() {
            $(this).empty().droppable("enable");
            });
        var dropbox = $('#dropbox').html();
        var dropbox1 = $('#dropbox1').html();

    if(dropbox && dropbox1 !== ''){
        $.post("account_main.php", 
          {data: $(this).text()}, 
          function(data) {
               //alert("Data saved.");
               $('#demo').html(data);
          });       
        }
        }
    });
```

I am pretty sure `{data:$this.text()}` is the issue, but I'm brainlocked on how I can echo the other dropped elements when the last droppable element is dropped.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you simply echo the content of the dropboxes?

```
alert($('#dropbox1').text());
alert($('#dropbox2').text());
```

or are you trying to echo them in the order they were dropped?